# Select the most recent entry for a key with relevant sub-values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL table with data like the following.

```
key  entry_no  type_1  type_2  text
1    1         A       Y       text 1
1    2         B       Y       text 2
1    3         B       Y       text 3
1    4         A       Y       text 4
1    5         B               text 5       
1    6         C       Y       text 6
```

What I need to do is for a specified key (e.g. 1) extract the rows with the highest entry_no for each type_1 group (e.g. A, B or C) where type_2 equals "Y".

E.g. From the above I want to return the following:

```
key  entry_no  type_1  type_2  text
1    3         B       Y       text 3
1    4         A       Y       text 4
1    6         C       Y       text 6
```

I've tried a few different ways to do this but can't get it right (I'm no SQL expert, though). Is this possible?

I assume I need to do some type of sub-query?

Comment: Please edit the question and add a tag with the DBMS that you use (Postgres, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) and its version. Unless, you need a solution in ANSI standard SQL.

Comment: Tags updated as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this type of query is called `top-N-per-group`. In SQL Server there are at least two methods to get the result. One uses `ROW_NUMBER`, another `CROSS APPLY`. If you have a lot of groups and few rows per group, then it is more efficient to use `ROW_NUMBER`. If you have few groups, but each group has a lot of rows, and you have an appropriate index, it is more efficient to use `CROSS APPLY`.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group

http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/seek-and-you-shall-scan-part-i-when-optimizer-doesnt-optimize

**Sample data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
    ([key] int, 
    [entry_no] int, 
    [type_1] varchar(1), 
    [type_2] varchar(1), 
    [text] varchar(50));

INSERT INTO @T
    ([key], [entry_no], [type_1], [type_2], [text])
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'A', 'Y', 'text 1'),
    (1, 2, 'B', 'Y', 'text 2'),
    (1, 3, 'B', 'Y', 'text 3'),
    (1, 4, 'A', 'Y', 'text 4'),
    (1, 5, 'B', '',  'text 5'),
    (1, 6, 'C', 'Y', 'text 6');
```

**Variant with ROW_NUMBER**

```
DECLARE @VarKey int = 1;

WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        [key]
        ,[entry_no]
        ,[type_1]
        ,[type_2]
        ,[text]
        ,ROW_NUMBER() 
            OVER (PARTITION BY [type_1] ORDER BY [entry_no] DESC) AS rn
    FROM @T
    WHERE   
        [key] = @VarKey
        AND [type_2] = 'Y'
)
SELECT
    [key]
    ,[entry_no]
    ,[type_1]
    ,[type_2]
    ,[text]
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY [type_1];
```

**Result**

```
| key | entry_no | type_1 | type_2 | text   |
|-----|----------|--------|--------|--------|
| 1   | 4        | A      | Y      | text 4 |
| 1   | 3        | B      | Y      | text 3 |
| 1   | 6        | C      | Y      | text 6 |
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(entry_no)
from table
group by type_1
where key = 1 and type_2 = 'Y'
```

Comment: This is a nice, simple solution (although it does make me want to cry a bit). How can I return the "text" field and the "type_1" field as well?

Comment: I guess not in a single statement as you had to group by text and type_1 as well and these values are not equal for a single entry_no.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as (
     select 1  as [key]  , 1  as entry_no      , 'A'   as type_1     ,'Y'   as type_2     ,'text 1' as [text]
    union select 1   , 2        , 'B'       ,'Y'       ,'text 2'
    union select 1   , 3        , 'B'       ,'Y'       ,'text 3'
    union select 1   , 4        , 'A'       ,'Y'       ,'text 4'
    union select 1   , 5        , 'B'       ,' '       ,'text 5'       
    union select 1   , 6        , 'C'       ,'Y'       ,'text 6'
    ) 
    select *From cte
    where entry_no = (select max(entry_no) from cte t  where cte.[key] = t.[key] and cte.type_1 = t.type_1 and t.type_2='Y')
```